# How to avoid seen white background at the top?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

If I scroll at the top and then if I want to scroll down sometimes I see the white background, I've set the margin to 0 but I have seen web pages that do not have this kind of behaviour, any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: You can set background color as blue for body, so that white space will be blue and no white space will be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to set body background color the same as your header or use this code to prevent over-scrolling.

```css
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for, thank you @Edvards